# Get string between a and b

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
&report1=1616078531&report2=1850168139&report3=5957523384&report4=5781950301&END
```

I'm trying to get the report number (between "&report" and "=") for (in this example) the report with the ID #1850168139 (result = 2). I'm using a simple get_string_between function, but it doesn't work because it gives me the entire string from the first occurence of "&report" in the string.

Example:

```
$report_number = get_string_between($reports_list_id, "&report", "=".$report_id."&");
```

Where $report_list_id is the above string, and $report_id is 1850168139.

The results it gives me is:

```
1=1616078531&report2
```

But what I need is to get only "2".

Been struggling on that one. Will appreciate any help I can get!

EDIT: In case you were wondering, here is the get_string_between() function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
  $string = " ".$string;
  $ini = strpos($string,$start);
  if ($ini == 0) return "";
  $ini += strlen($start);
  $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
  return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

It's a pretty simple function that gets the job done in most cases, but it's not really helping here.

Comment: `get_string_between()` isn't a PHP function. So do you use a framework?

Comment: You should probably use `parse_str` to parse the query string and then parse the key manually when you find your match (in a loop...).

Comment: @Rizier123 quick googling seems to indicate that it's something in Wordpress.

Comment: No there is no framework (unfortunately), it's a custom PHP site.

Comment: If it is a part of URL then simple you can REQUEST the variable.Like $report1 = $_REQUEST['report1'];

Comment: What you have there is a string in URL query format. That's a defined format for which dedicated parse functions exist. Use those. Don't do manual string manipulation when you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately no, it is not a URL (although it sure looks like one) but a string loaded externally via PHP/MySQL. I just need a function to get the "last string" between 2 strings, essentially.

Comment: It may not *be* a URL, but it sure looks like one: http://3v4l.org/23Y6T

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Parameters like as follows.If you are wanting to get the parameters report1,report2,report3 & report4 then it will help you.

```
<?php
    $string = '&report1=1616078531&report2=1850168139&report3=5957523384&report4=5781950301&END';
    parse_str($string, $url_parts);
    //print_r(url_parts);
    $report1 = $url_parts['report1'];
    $report2 = $url_parts['report2'];
    $report3 = $url_parts['report3'];
    $report4 = $url_parts['report4'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good approach to your problem. You need a userdefined function that takes in the report ID and the entire masterstring as arguments.

In that function, you will need to construct a regex pattern (Using positive look-ahead) like the following:

```
report(\d)=(?=MyReportIDToBeTested)
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/iD0fZ4/1

Next, you will need to test with the newly constructed regex on the master string. If it fails, you should return something like 0 and break off the function.

If the test is successful, tell it to return the first capturing group which should be your report ID.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm an HTML/front-end guy and PHP/backends aren't my cup of tea, how would I go around what you just said? Writing $report_number = report(\d)=(?=$report_id) won't work by itself I suppose?

Comment: No, no, no. When you're constructing a regex pattern, you're basically constructing a string, so I think it would be something like `Pattern = "report(\d)=(?=" +  $reportID + ")"`  I'm not a PHP developer myself (More like VB.net) but I believe my algorithm approach would work just fine for you. You also need to check if the reportID is all numeric.